# Ubuntu boot hangs

Tags: 12.04, boot, unity

I'm using Ubuntu LTS12.04 and I'm having a serious issue.
When I boot my computer, the Ubuntu starting screen (with the 5 dots) is loading, the dots are filling but then the process hangs (the 5 dots are full but nothing happens).
I can still get the console interface through ctrl+alt+F1.
So I try to restart the "display manager" (not sure what I'm talking about) with the following command:

```
sudo service lightdm restart
```

This command returns me no error, but when I'm switching back to the graphical interface (with alt+F7), the following message is hanging

```
Checking Battery state ....
```

Any piece of advice would be appreciated !

Regards,
Nicolas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

Go into Ctrl + Alt + F1 and type

```
sudo apt-get install gdm
```

Comment: This is what I have finally did. It worked !

Comment: I'm glad it worked, I hadn't tried it (never had that problem). You could have just looked it up, though. It was easy to find. ;)

Answer (score 0):

First place recommended to start, check your computer system specifications. Refer to:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_(operating_system)#System_requirements

It may simply be that you do not have the suggested processor speed/graphics/Ram combination to handle this distro?
Might want to consider running Xubuntu or Lubuntu if your speed/ram/graphics combination is boarder line? If you are satisfied that your system can handle this distro,then several other solutions may be indicated. For example, boot loader problems etc..

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using NOMODESET boot kernel parameter?

I'm guessing you try to boot the LiveCD and you don't have it installed (as this would actually require previous successful booting of the LiveCD).

Please see this for boot kernel parameters (see section "How to enable kernel options on the livecd (before install)"): http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1613132