# Ubuntu Trusty hangs at boot

Tags: boot, 14.04

Friday I installed upgrades, then shutdown my computer for the week-end.
This morning (monday) my Ubuntu hangs at boot.
The "loading dots" screen become a black screen, then nothing happens.

If I press the power switch, the system seems to unload correctly, and stops.

Some times it says that it has issues loading the swap so I tried this solution : [Cryptswap boot error - can't mount?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/224369/cryptswap-boot-error-cant-mount)
It didn't work.

Then I tried to log as root, remount / with rw `mount -o remount /`, activate my network by modifying **/etc/network/interfaces**, and update packages `apt-get update
apt-get dist-upgrade
apt-get upgrade`
It does not helped.

I'm newbie to Ubuntu so I'm not sure where to find boot error messages (if they exist), I looked in **/var/log/boot.log** and **/var/log/bootstrap.log** but did not find any error clearly written.

This is my work computer, so I'd like to resolv the issue asap.
Is it possible to force a full packages reinstall ? Or a system reinstall while keeping my personal files and configuration ?

**edit1:**
According to [Ubuntu boot hangs](https://askubuntu.com/questions/508135/ubuntu-boot-hangs), I tried to set gdm as the default X.
This changed nothing.

Thanks,

Bastien Semene